# Interesting Sum of $\frac {1}{n^2 +n+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I was working on a problem and came across this sum

$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac {1}{r^2 +r+1}$

I tried using a complex factorisation but that doesnt seem to work?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Do you mean a **closed form formula** for this finite sum ? Besides, may I ask you why you consider this sum as more "interesting" than others for example $\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac {1}{r^2 -r+1}$ or $\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac {1}{r^2 +r-1}$... ? Beware of jealousy betwen finite sums.

Comment: @JeanMarie , what jealousy? give example

Comment: the sum containes the poly gamma function

Comment: complex factorisation and fraction decomposition work and lead to a result  if you know the generalized harmonic numbers.

Comment: @Arjang It was about the title "interesting sum". Never heard a sum saying another one "I am more interesting than you" ?

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\sum_{k\leq n}\frac{1}{k^{2}+k+1}=\sum_{k\leq n}\frac{1}{\left(k-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(k-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}
 $$ $$=-i\sqrt{3}\left(\sum_{k\leq n}\frac{1}{k-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}}-\sum_{k\leq n}\frac{1}{k-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)
 $$ and now we can write the series in terms of the Digamma function, using the relation $$\psi\left(x+N\right)-\psi\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{k+x}.$$